# Set the option value of drop box to value retrieving from db in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

{!! Form::select('grade', array('' => 'Select A Grade')+$grade,null,['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'grade']) !!}

Above is the drop box code. There I need to set the option values also to the values retrieving from db. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**In Controller:**

```
Class yourController extends Controller {

    protected $gradeList;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->gradeList = ['' => 'Select A Grade'] + Grade::lists('name', 'id')->all();
    }

    // suppose you want to get it i index method

    public function index() {
        $gradeArray = $this->gradeList;
        return view('yourBladeTemplate', compact('gradeArray');
    }

}
```

**In Blade Template**

```
{!! Form::select('id', $gradeArray , Input::old('id') , array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
```

Comment: What did u mean by grade_id in the blade. Is it just the name for drop box?  $this->gradeList = ['' => 'Select A Grade'] + Grade::lists('name', 'id')->all();  And there all() method can't call due to an exception

Comment: Where did u edit? Still get this following error.      Call to a member function all() on array